# How Add Icon in project?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use icons in my project, I add icons like this:

```
<a href="#">
  <i class="icon-display4"></i> 
  <span class="visible-xs-inline-block position-right"> start</span>
</a>
```

And add I link them in `<head>`:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

But the icons don't show.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What icon are you trying to add? A font awesome icon?

Comment: this page is a ready panel,I Don't Know Sorry

Comment: You are missing the `fa` class in the `i` tag and check the font-awesome cheat-sheet for the list of icons available.

Comment: While you have a problem with some icon collection. First of all try to use documentation, because it involves every thing you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Font Awesome Icon To Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39422828/add-font-awesome-icon-to-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your icon actually exists. It looks like you're trying to use:

```
<i class="icon-user-tie">
```

But a search on the [official website](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) doesn't show this one as being an active icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can add font awesome icons with example:

```
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
```

Here a list with all the icons from font awesome:
http://fontawesome.io/icons/

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand the question, but I think this might be what you are looking for:

to add images, then use the  tag, the syntax goes like this:

```
<img src="image location like https://i.imgur.com/HLXsgMd.jpg">
```

for linked images then put the image inside the a tag, like this:

```
<a href="#"><img src="image location"></a>
```

to make a favicon (the icon that appears next to the page title) this should work:

**Please do note that it has to be a `.ico` file** see [here](https://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-ico).

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="image location">`

Comment: The OP is asking about how to use font icons and not just images. In this case the OP is using font-awesome.

Answer (score 0):

**If you Want To Use Icons In Your Page Then You Have to Use awesome icons**

Go-to:  http://fontawesome.io/icons/

> First You Need To Add Font Awesome Css File On Your Page. then After You Can Used It any where in page.

Add This : `<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

**For example, I'm using this icon:**

`<i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>`

Answer (score 0):

If by 'icons' you mean Bootstrap Glyphicons, I recommend visiting https://www.w3schools.com/icons/bootstrap_icons_glyphicons.asp, they also come predefined with bootstrap standard plugins e.g. glyphicons-halflings-regular files.